# Como puedo guardar el userInput en Windows Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Quisiera saber cual es la mejor forma de poder guardar las informaciones que un usuario entra en diferentes textBox en una aplicacion de Windows Form.

He leido varios foros recomendando de guardar el todo en un archivo XML.

Lo que estoy buscando hacer esque cada vez que se inicie la aplicacion, este pueda recordar que informacion se entro la vez anterior que la aplicacion se ejecuto.

Cual es la mejor forma de hacer esto?

Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: No evaluaste usar una base de datos, puede ser algo simple como SQLite, Sql Compact o Ms Access ? porque persistir a un archivo si para guardar y recuperar datos existen las base de datos

Comment: @LeandroTuttini, lo pense pero no me convendria ya que la aplicacion la usarian varios otros usarios sin tener posibilidad de estar en el mismo network de la base de datos. Tendria que guardar los datos pero hacer la aplicacion que se pueda ejecutar de cualquier lado (aplicacion basada en servicios web)

Comment: las db que mencione puedes usarlas en cualquier pc sin necesidad de instalar ningun motor de base de datos, quizas podrias evaluar SQLite o Sql Compact

Comment: ah ok no habia contenplado eso, tienes alguna sugerencia de como poder inplementarlo?

Comment: que db piensas implementar sql compact es una buena opcion

Answer (score 1):

Si son datos muy sencillos no necesitas de una base de datos ni tampoco un xml, eso lo puedes hacer con un archivo de settings en el proyecto ya sea de tipo user o application.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si persiste en una db Sql Compact no necesitas ningun motor de base de datos en el cliente

[SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1)

[Usar SQL Server Compact (Visual Studio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa983321(v=vs.110).aspx)

Agregas la db como item en el proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y programas como cualqueir otra base de datos usar las clase de ado.net

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();   
using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("connection string"))   
{   
    string query = "select id, desc from <tabla>";   

    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, conn);   

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);     
    da.Fill(dt);   
}
```

En este caso usas las clases con prefijo `SqlCe` usando las clases de [System.Data.SqlServerCe Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)